# How to create a text file and write text character by character using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How to create a text file and write text character by character using MATLAB?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a text file using this command

```
fileID = fopen('my_file_name.txt','w');
```

if the file is existing and you wish to append a string to the end of the file use

```
fileID = fopen('my_file_name.txt','a');
```

and you can write a string using fprintf

```
my_string = 'hello world';
fprintf(fileID, '%s', my_string);
```

after you are done, close the file

```
fclose(fileID);
```